# How to change default style for unstyled input elements

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, customization

Resorting to StackOverflow because weirdly enough I wasn't able to find an answer in Firefox docs or community.

I am trying to change the default style for form and input elements such as:

- buttons
- radios
- checkboxes
- select
- number

Once changed these should be the default styles of the browser and any over site CSS that specifies styles for these elements should override the new default Firefox style.

I am surprised there isn't a themes/styles Firefox market (or similar) to customize your Firefox default style, especially since Firefox is very pro customization. So if there are I'd appreciate if I could be pointd towards them.

I did manage to change the scrollbard completely via userChrome using [this floating scrollbar](https://github.com/Endor8/userChrome.js/blob/master/floatingscrollbar/FloatingScrollbar.uc.js). However if my understanding is correct, `userChrome.js` and `userChrome.css` is to customize and style the browser elements themselves, not the actual HTML contents of the page.